# How can i check User Role in javascript (without razor or controller)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, user-roles

I'm trying to use User.IsInRole() with javascript like on the razor page. I don't want use Controller, if this can be done, How can i do this in MVC5?

Edit: I want to display button by user role. I can do this with the razor page. There are fields in javascript where I add elements to the table, I will try to use them here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below as shown below in for price

```
@{var price=20;}
<html>
<body>
@if (price>30)
  {
  <p>The price is too high.</p>
  }
else
  {
  <p>The price is OK.</p>
  }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
//Check login User has 'System Administrator' role
function CheckUserRole() {
    var currentUserRoles = Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentUserRoles.length; i++) {
         var userRoleId = currentUserRoles[i];
    var userRoleName = GetRoleName(userRoleId);
        if (userRoleName == "System Administrator") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 
//Get Rolename based on RoleId
function GetRoleName(roleId) {
    //var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var serverUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
    var odataSelect = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc" + "/" + "RoleSet?$filter=RoleId eq guid'" + roleId + "'";
    var roleName = null;
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: odataSelect,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                roleName = data.d.results[0].Name;
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + textStatus + errorThrown + odataSelect); }
        }
    );
    return roleName;
}
```

https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/get-login-user-role-names-in-javascript-in-dynamics-crm-2011/